# Describe the elements in the following set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$x \notin \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}\diagdown \bigcup\limits_{j\in J}B_{j} $

This was a problem on exam and I think the correct answer should be 
$x$ such that $x \notin A_i$ for some $i \in I$ or $x \in B_j$ for some $j \in J$

The only answer close to this on the test(multiple choice) was $x \notin A_i$ for some $i \in I$ and $x \in B_j$ for some $j \in J$

Other answers were:

$x \notin A_i$ for some $i \in I$ and $x \in B_j$ for all $j \in J$

$x \notin A_i$ for all $i \in I$ and $x \in B_j$ for some $j \in J$

$x \notin A_i$ for all $i \in I$ and $x \in B_j$ for all $j \in J$

Which one is correct(if any!) also is there a different way to express the first statement using and?

Comment: This is equivalent to $$x\notin\bigcap A_i, B_j^c$$So, we have $x$ is in some $A_i^c$ or some $B_j$, $x\in\bigcup A_i^c,B_j$.

Comment: sorry your notation is confusing me the only answers on the test were for $x$ not in $A$ and $x$ in $B$ Sorry are any of the to statements above correct?

Comment: @DonThousand so the first answer above is correct?Is there any way to express the answer with a conjuctive instead of a disjunctive. Also I am sorry I have not seen the notation with the "c" before>

Comment: @DonThousand I have added the rest of the answers to the problem.Are any of the above answers correct?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. The answer should be "or" not "and".  If $x$ is not in any $A_i$ nor any $B_j$ it will not be in the set.  If it's in any of the $B_j$ it not in the set but that isn't the only way to avoid it.  It could be in none of the $B_j$ and not be in the set if it's not in all the $A_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The test is in error and you are right.  This can occur if $x \not \in \cap A_i$, and it can occur if $x \in \cup B_j$.  But it isn't *required* that *both* be true.  Just one or the other.  SO it should be "OR"; not "AND".

===

If $x \not \in \cap_{i\in I}A_i \setminus \cup_{j\in J}B_j$

The $x$ is not in all $A_i$ *unless* $x$ is in some $B_j$.

If that isn't clear then consider.

$\cap_{i\in I}A_i$ is just the elements in *all* the $A_i$.  What's not in that set are the elements in some but not all $A_i$ and the elements that aren't in any $A_i$.

$ \cap_{i\in I}A_i \setminus \cup_{j\in J}B_j$ are just the elements in *all* the $A_i$ unless they also are in $\cup_{j\in J}B_j$.  Any element in any or some of the $B_j$ will be excluded.  So $ \cap_{i\in I}A_i \setminus \cup_{j\in J}B_j$ are the elements in all the $A_i$ but not in any of $B_j$.

So the way $x$ might *not* be in $ \cap_{i\in I}A_i \setminus \cup_{j\in J}B_j$ is if it *isn't* in all the $A_i$ (it might be in some of them but not all) or if it *is* in all the $A_i$ it can avoid being in $ \cap_{i\in I}A_i \setminus \cup_{j\in J}B_j$ if it is in any or some of the $B_j$.

In other words the answer you picked:

$x$ is either not in all $A_i$ which means there are some (maybe all) $A_i$ that don't contain $x$ OR $x$ is in one or more of the $B_j$.

The test was in error.

It is not required that either $x$ is not in all $A_i$ (it could by in all $A_i$ but also in at least one $B_j$) or that it must be in any $B_j$ (it could be in none of the $B_j$ but not be in some of the $A_i$).  It is only required that one or the other be true. It's not required that both be true.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is definitely is not correct, because x which doesn't lie in any B, and doesn't lie in some A is also satisfy description in the task

First one seems correct

Maybe x not lie in some A and x lie in Union of all sets (UAi)U(UBj)

Comment: So $x\notin A_i$ for some $i$ and $x\in B_j$ for all $j$? Would this one be correct?

Comment: Your comment is making me really confused, are any of the above answers correct?

Comment: No, because it doesn't count elements which lie for example in A1, and don't lie in any other sets, but initial description includes them (answer for the first comment)

Comment: This one seems correct to me  x such that x∉Ai for some i∈I or x∈Bj for some j∈J

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that one was not included on the test

Comment: is it possible for initial set to be interpreted like this?
(x∉⋂Ai)╲⋃Bj

Then the answer would be like
x∉Ai  for some i and x∉Bj for all j